# UnauthorizedAccessException at storageFile.OpenReadAsync

Tags: c#, stream, uwp, buffer, storage

The user can take multiple pictures. These pictures are stored in ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder:

```
folderBatch = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Batch", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

When the user takes a picture, this method is fired:

```
    public async void GetAndProcessImage()
    {
           IBuffer ImageBuffer = null;

            if (App.settings.ImageSource == MyImageSource.Camera)
                ImageBuffer = await Camera.TakePhotoAsync();

            // store in batch folder
            IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> listFiles = await folderBatch.GetFilesAsync();
            int iNumberOfFiles = listFiles.Count;
            StorageFile fileTarget = await folderBatch.CreateFileAsync(string.Format("batch{0}.jpg", iNumberOfFiles));
            IRandomAccessStream filestream = await fileTarget.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            await filestream.GetOutputStreamAt(0).WriteAsync(ImageBuffer);
            await filestream.FlushAsync();
}
```

The pictures are taken with this method, called by GetAndProcessImage above:

```
    public async Task<IBuffer> TakePhotoAsync()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("taking picture...");
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        if (mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Supported)
            await mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync();

        try
        {
            await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ExceptionHandler.Instance.HandleException(e);
        }
        IBuffer ibuffer = await StreamHelpers.StreamToIBuffer(stream);
        return ibuffer;
    }
```

When the user is done, he/she can push a push a button to start reading the batch files:

```
MyFile file = new KNFBFile(string.Format("{0}\\{1}.knfb", ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, string.Format("Batch-{0:yyyyMMdd-hh-mm-ss-tt}", DateTime.Now)));
uint iCount = 0;
foreach (StorageFile filebatch in listFiles)
{
     await App.converter.ConvertBatchJPG(filebatch);
     IRandomAccessStream imagestream = await StreamHelpers.IBufferToStream(App.ocr.LastImageBuffer);
     file.SavePage(iCount++, imagestream);
}
```

This method is now called:

```
 public async Task ConvertBatchJPG(StorageFile fileSource)
 {
      IRandomAccessStream JPGStream = await fileSource.OpenReadAsync();
```

-->the method above (OpenReadAsync) causes the exception
     ...
     }

Comment: You are not disposing the streams - try to put them into `using(IRandomAccessStream ...) { // here code done with the stream }`, this should ensure they are disposed.

Comment: i tried it already, didn't help, i'll give it another try though

Comment: Also, sometimes it works perfectly, other times it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dispose the `filestream` **and** the `outputstream` you are retrieving:

```
StorageFile fileTarget = await folderBatch.CreateFileAsync(string.Format("batch{0}.jpg", iNumberOfFiles));
using(IRandomAccessStream filestream = await fileTarget.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    using(var outStream = filestream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
    {
        await outStream.WriteAsync(ImageBuffer);
    }
    await filestream.FlushAsync();
 }
```

Since you are not altering the stream returned by `OpenAsync()`, you can also avoid creating an intermediary output stream:

```
using(IRandomAccessStream filestream = await fileTarget.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    await filestream .WriteAsync(ImageBuffer);
    await filestream.FlushAsync();
 }
```